# Tree View in SQL

Tags: sql, treeview

Is there a simple way of doing a expanded tree view within SQL Select statement using the Output to Text in SQL Server Management Studio?

Input Table

```
GRP NAME ITEM1 ITEM2
--- ---- ----- -----
 1   AB   100   200
 1   AC   150   200
 1   AD   175   200
 2   BC   200   220
 2   BD   NULL  NULL
```

Desired output

```
GRP 1
+-- AB
+    +-- ITEM1: 100
+    +-- ITEM2: 200
+-- AC
+    +-- ITEM1: 150
+    +-- ITEM2: 200
+-- AD
+    +-- ITEM1: 175
+    +-- ITEM2: 200

GRP 2
+-- BC
+    +-- ITEM1: 200
+    +-- ITEM2: 220
+-- BD
```

Thanks
jlimited

Answer (score 0):

This will do (you will need to ignore columns 2,3,4 in the output, they are there for ordering):

```
select DISTINCT 'GRP ' + convert(varchar(10), GRP), convert(int, GRP), ' ', 0 from table1
UNION ALL
select '+-- ' + [NAME], convert(int, GRP), [name], 1 from table1
UNION ALL
select '+    +-- ITEM 1: ' + [ITEM1], convert(int, GRP), [name], 2 from table1 where ITEM1 IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
select '+    +-- ITEM 2: ' + [ITEM2], convert(int, GRP), [name], 3 from table1 where ITEM2 IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY 2,3,4
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/89de7/2)